# Session and cookies-NodeJS and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

I have question considering sessions and session cookies in NodeJS. I will first provide some code that is related to adjusting session package in nodeJS, and couple of routes I have.

```
const session = require('express-session');
const mongodbStore = require('connect-mongodb-session');
const demoRoutes = require('./routes/demo');
const MongoDBStore = mongodbStore(session);

const app = express();

const sessionStore = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',
  databaseName: 'auth-demo',
  collection:'sessions'
});

app.use(session({
  secret: 'super-secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: sessionStore,
}));

app.use(demoRoutes);

/*now we have routes in demo.js file*/

router.post('/login', async function (req, res) {
  const userData = req.body;
  const enteredEmail = userData.email;
  const enteredPassword = userData.password;

  const existingUser = await db.getDb().collection('users').findOne({email:enteredEmail});

  if(!existingUser) {
    req.session.inputData = {
      hasError:true,
      message:'Could not log you in-check your credentials!',
      email:enteredEmail,
      password:enteredPassword
    };
    req.session.save(function(){
      res.redirect('/login');
    })
    return;
   
  }
  
  const passwordsAreEqual = await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, existingUser.password);

  if(!passwordsAreEqual) {
    req.session.inputData = {
      hasError:true,
      message:'Could not log you in-check your credentials!',
      email:enteredEmail,
      password:enteredPassword
    };
    req.session.save(function(){
      res.redirect('/login');
    });
    return;
  }
  req.session.user = { id: existingUser._id, email:existingUser.email};
  req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
  req.session.save(function() {
    res.redirect('/profile');
  })
});

router.post('/logout', function (req, res) {
  req.session.user = null;
  req.session.isAuthenticated = false;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Now I have questions:
First, when session is created with save function, then cookie which contains session id is sent to client and then stored in browser.  Then, if I got that right, with every new request sent cookie is sent with that request, and then parsed with session package to session with the same id that cookie contains. Now, when some user logs out(route /logout) session is not deleted, I only modify authentication properties, and that means cookie of that user will still exists, because, again session is not deleted. If then another user logs in from same machine, cookie from previous user is sent with that login request right(?)(because that cookie is still there), and then req.session from post login route will actually be the session of previous user. So, I don't get how is new session, with new id created for every user when we have cookie of previous user, that will be parsed into session of that user(who had that cookie).This is a bit confusing to me, if someone could clarify this would be very thankful.